# Sencha Touch 2 Ajax Proxy not showing data in list

Tags: ajax, proxy, touch, extjs

Hopefully someone can help.. I've searched for hours trying to find a solution to this..

I'm trying to populate a list using an ajax proxy in a store. If I put the json data inline, it works perfectly but I can't seem to get any data returned from the proxy even though the url is returning the exact same json data in the browser. What am I doing wrong???

Store:

```
Ext.define('m3.store.News', {  
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',  

requires: ['m3.model.News'],  

config: {  
    model: 'm3.model.News',  
    autoload: true,  
    proxy: {  
        type: 'ajax',  
        url: 'http://localhost/lib',  
        reader: {  
            type: 'json'  
        }  
    }  
});
```

If I add the data inline, it works perfectly:

```
Ext.define('m3.store.News', {  
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',  

requires: ['m3.model.News'],  

config: {  
    model: 'm3.model.News',  
    autoload: true,  
    proxy: {  
        type: 'ajax',  
        url: 'http://localhost/lib',  
        reader: {  
            type: 'json'  
        }  
    },  
data: [{"title":"Test Title 1","id":"1","text":"<div>Test Text 1<\/div>"},{"title":"Test Title 2","id":"2","text":"<div>Test Text 2<\/div>"}]  
});
```

Everything else is working fine so I'm not posting the other files, let me know if you might need them.

I've even tried static json files but nothing seems to get returned from the proxy.

Is there a way to test the response from the proxy in Console? I've tried "Ext.getStore('News');" but it returns an empty array.

Using Sencha Touch 2 MVC.

It seems so simple but I just can't get it working.. many thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, tried Ext.getStore('News').load(); in the console and it pulls the data in.. Now, I can't figure out where to put that call in the app.. Newbie territory I'm afraid.. Thanks..

Comment: Just added it to the Launch function in the main app.js and all seems to be working fine.. So what's the deal with "autoload"? Is that config not supposed to do that??

Comment: Aaaaagggghhhhh! autoLoad not autoload!!!!!!!!!!!! Noob central..

Answer (score 0):

I think what your are missing here is the `rootProperty` while loading the `data` through `Ajax` proxy.

You need to mention this property to identify the root of your json.

```
reader : {
   type:'json',
   rootProperty:'data'
}
```

and your json data should be of the format like below (root should be "data")

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "Test Title 1",
            "id": "1",
            "text": "<div>Test Text 1</div>"
        },
        {
            "title": "Test Title 2",
            "id": "2",
            "text": "<div>Test Text 2</div>"
        }
    ]
}
```

I think, it should work now with these changes.